# How to generate unique number of 12 digits?

Tags: c#, unique, uniqueidentifier

I'm working on an app that sends raw data to zebra printer and print out barcodes. And since every item has its own unique barcode, I need to define a variable that automatically generates unique number of 12 digits long.

see example:

```
printBar prnt = new printBar("123456789012");
```

Is there anyway to define a double variable and pass it to a function that return uniqely 12 digits number and pass it over again to the printBar class?. But how to make sure everytime you access it returns a unique value?.

I also thought of another way, since am using MS Access db, I can create a column of AutoNumber datatype and assign it to Random, but you don't get the exact 12 digits required, sometimes it generates a value of 10 digits sometimes more or less.

Comment: Can you just add 0's to the front of that 10 digit number?

Comment: How many do you need, and do they just need to be unique for a given run, or do they have to be unique "forever"?

Comment: I need it to be limitless and unique forever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680683/12-digit-unique-id-code-reliability

Comment: "I need it to be limitless and unique forever" - there are by definition only 10^12 12-digit numbers. One day you will run out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an RNG and a hash do:

10 - stream out 12 digits

20 - check if value is in hash

30 - if it's goto 40 else goto 10

40 - push value into hash

50 - return new 12 digit number 

60 - goto 10

Comment: Here is what I did:

static Random r = new Random();

static int randomId()
        {
            int n = r.Next(999999999999);
            return n;
        }
And it works. Every call to randomId() returns random number.

Comment: @Dan: Yes it returns a **random number** but **not unique number**. To get a unique one you have to know which numbers you already have created or you have to use some other uniqueness (like date/time stamp)!

Comment: @Dan: Just a current description, about what you did and what are the aftermath: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Start with a twelve digit number, ie: 111111111111

to get your new 'random' unique number take the previous number and add 1.

although not random, it will guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks, but the value will reset on app restart. Could u plz post a sample code?.

Comment: store the value in a common location, such as a database, and generate the number from there.

Answer (score 6):

How many times do you generate a new barcode per day, hour, minute?

You could use a technique like the auto versioning of Visual Studio works.

- Count the number of days from some specific date (e.g. 1.1.2000)

  - padded with 0 to five places.
- Concat the seconds elapsed till midnight

  - padded also with zero to five places.
- Fill up the last two numbers with a static counter in your App that just wrap around at 99.

#### Example

```
public static class UniqueId
{
    static private int _InternalCounter = 0;

    static public string Get()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        var days = (int)(now - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).TotalDays;
        var seconds = (int)(now - DateTime.Today).TotalSeconds;

        var counter = _InternalCounter++ % 100;

        return days.ToString("00000") + seconds.ToString("00000") + counter.ToString("00");
    }
```

With this approach you'll get an overflow at the 15. October 2273, but i think this can be solved by your follower. ;-)

If you need to create more than hundred unique IDs per second you can change the last two line into:

```
var counter = _InternalCounter++ % 1000;
return days.ToString("0000") + seconds.ToString("00000") + counter.ToString("000");
```

Now you'll have thousand unique IDs per second, but the days will already overflow at 18. May 2027. If this is too short, you can get additional ten years if you set the start date to 2010 by this line:

```
var days = (int)(now - new DateTime(2010, 1, 1)).TotalDays;
```

Comment: Your code can generate number of 12 digits, but it isn't good in security mode because the number is easy to guess what coming next after generated.

Comment: @TriNguyenDung: Having a unique number and a random (not predictible) unique number are different things. If you need the second one my approach won't work, but that was not the question.