# c# winform How to generate a ticket number

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox called Pass #. Each time I add a new entry I want it to generate a number or next sequence number. Can't find a straightforward conclusion. The information is stored in a Datagrid (Access Database). 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "generate a number" exactly mean? A random one? Between which values? Or the next number in an ordered sequence? Please, provide some info.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to generate the number or how to display your information on your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a completely random number each time i would recommending looking at this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942489/generating-multiple-random-numbers).

Although you may want to add in a method that then stores the numbers created in an array and then compares the newly randomly generate number with the new one. Like so:

```
    List<Numbers> list = new List<Numbers>();
    List.Add(new Numbers(newNumber));
    if(List.Contains(newNumber){
        //Run the generate new number method again here
    }else{
        //Whatever you want to do with the number afterwards
    }
```

Just had a basic glance over. I hope it helps in some way of the code side, if not, maybe just the thought process.

Thanks.

Yes it is a list array from strings when numbers are involved

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a number, You could want to save it in a file instead of database for future use.

```
        int prev;
        //Reads the id file to see what's previous id num
        using (StreamReader a = new StreamReader("Id.txt"))
        {
            prev = int.Parse(a.ReadLine());
        }
        //Shows one more of previous value
        MessageBox.Show((prev+1).ToString());
        //Overwrites value for future use
        using (StreamWriter b = new StreamWriter("Id.txt"))
        {
            b.Write((prev+1).ToString());
        }
```